# Wget other user's private repository on Github

Tags: git, shell, command-line

What terminal command should I use to wget a private repository in a .tar.gz or .zip format?

The private repository in question does not belong to me, but to another user who I am in team with, and who granted me full access to it when I authorize with my Github login and password.

I want to wget this repository to a server where there are no git binaries installed.

This is a workaround I thought about to deploy the application on this server since FTPing the files would take too much time.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Why don't you `git clone` to a machine where you do have Git, then take it from there?

Comment: It's just that the target server is really far away so I do not want to upload to it because last time I did it it took something like 8 hrs to push 15MB. I have shell access to it though so it will be much quicker to wget or curl a repo once I'm in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about wget, but with curl, it would be:

```
curl -u <token>:x-oauth-basic -L https://github.com/user-or-org/repo/archive/sha1-or-ref.tar.gz | tar xz
```

With `<token>` being your [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/applications).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have solved my problem by making the repo public then going into the target directory on the server and then calling `wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/$username/$repo/tarball/master -O master.tgz`. I was not able, however, to wget a private repo of another user to which I have access to. I tried adding `--post-data` with credentials to no avail.